# Date-fns is returning incorrect dates

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a collection of date strings stored in a database in this format:

`2018-06-28T14:06:26.524Z`

`2018-07-02T10:32:18.818Z`

`2018-07-06T15:08:50.233Z`

I need to convert these dates into a format like this on the frontend:

`28 June 2018 14:06:26`

`02 July 2018 10:32:18`

`06 July 2018 08:50:23`

My attempt at doing this using date-fns is:

```
format(new Date(date), 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:MM:ss')
```

The problem is that the dates returned from the above are incorrect:

`2018-06-28T14:06:26.524Z` returns `28 June 2018 15:06:26`

`2018-07-02T10:32:18.818Z` returns `02 July 2018 11:07:18`

`2018-07-06T15:08:50.233Z` returns `06 July 2018 16:07:50`

What am I doing wrong here and how to I fix this so the dates are returned correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You messed up the time:

`HH:mm:ss` not `HH:MM:ss`

`MM` is for month and `mm` is for minute - [docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/format)

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled `HH:MM:ss` should be `HH:mm:ss` look at this list for an explanation on all formats: [Date formats](https://gist.github.com/y-gagar1n/8469484)

**Example:**

> **dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:**  22 August 2006 06:30:07